# Shopping cart rendering item in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've managed to setup the HTML and JS functionality of what the cart should do as each button is clicked. My problem is that the JS is not rendering the cart items when the shop item is clicked and I can't figure out why.

My HTML does use Tailwind as it's styling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Code snippet:*

```css
function ready() {
    let removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger');
    for (let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        let button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    }

    let quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input');
    for (let i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        let input = quantityInputs[i];
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
    }

    let addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button');
    for (let i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        let button = addToCartButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase');
    let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('.cart-items')[0];
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild);
    }
    updateCartTotal();
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    let buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    updateCartTotal();
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    let input = event.target;
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1;
    }
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    let button = event.target;
    let shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
    let title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText;
    let price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText;
    let imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src;
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc);
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    let cartRow = document.createElement('div');
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row');
    let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    let cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title');
    for (let i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart');
            return
        };
    };
    let cartRowContents = `
        <div class="grid align-middle grid-cols-3 gap-2 my-4">
                <img class="h-28 w-28" src="${imageSrc}" alt="Product"/>
                    <div>
                        <h4>${price}</h4>
                        <h5 class="cart-price">$${price}</h5>
                        <span class="text-red-200 cursor-pointer remove-btn">Remove</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
    cartItems.append(cartRow);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    let cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    let cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row');
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        let cartRow = cartRows[i];
        let priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
        let quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0];
        let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''));
        let quantity = quantityElement.value;
        total = total + (price * quantity);
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total;
}

ready();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Generics | Store</title>
        <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <script src="store.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <nav class="main-nav nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store.html">STORE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="band-name band-name-large">The Generics</h1>
        </header>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">MUSIC</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 1</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Album 1.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$12.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 2</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Album 2.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$14.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button"type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 3</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Album 3.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$9.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 4</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Album 4.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$19.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">MERCH</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">T-Shirt</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Shirt.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$19.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Coffee Cup</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Cofee.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$6.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-total">
                <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
        </section>
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container main-footer-container">
                <h3 class="band-name">The Generics</h3>
                <ul class="nav footer-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/YouTube Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.spotify.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/Spotify Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/Facebook Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which shop item are you referring to? I can see the cart item when click add to cart.

Comment: I need the JS to render the items once the "ADD TO CART" button is clicked. So the addItemToCart function should render to the "cart-items" in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Generics | Store</title>
        <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <nav class="main-nav nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store.html">STORE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="band-name band-name-large">The Generics</h1>
        </header>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">MUSIC</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 1</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Album 1.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$12.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 2</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Album 2.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$14.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button"type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 3</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Album 3.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$9.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 4</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Album 4.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$19.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">MERCH</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">T-Shirt</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Shirt.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$19.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Coffee Cup</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/Cofee.png">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$6.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-total">
                <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
        </section>
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container main-footer-container">
                <h3 class="band-name">The Generics</h3>
                <ul class="nav footer-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/YouTube Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.spotify.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/Spotify Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/Facebook Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <script>
            function ready() {
            let removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger');
            for (let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
                let button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
                button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
            }

            let quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input');
            for (let i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
                let input = quantityInputs[i];
                input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
            }

            let addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button');
            for (let i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
                let button = addToCartButtons[i];
                button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
            }

            document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);
        }

        function purchaseClicked() {
            alert('Thank you for your purchase');
            let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('.cart-items')[0];
            while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
                cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild);
            }
            updateCartTotal();
        }

        function removeCartItem(event) {
            let buttonClicked = event.target;
            buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            updateCartTotal();
        }

        function quantityChanged(event) {
            let input = event.target;
            if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
                input.value = 1;
            }
            updateCartTotal();
        }

        function addToCartClicked(event) {
            let button = event.target;
            let shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
            let title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText;
            let price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText;
            let imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src;
            addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc);
            updateCartTotal();
        }

        function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
            let cartRow = document.createElement('div');
            cartRow.classList.add('cart-row');
            let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
            let cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title');
            for (let i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
                if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
                    alert('This item is already added to the cart');
                    return
                };
            };
            let cartRowContents = `
                <div class="grid align-middle grid-cols-3 gap-2 my-4">
                        <img class="h-28 w-28" src="${imageSrc}" alt="Product"/>
                            <div>
                                <h4>${price}</h4>
                                <h5 class="cart-price">${price}</h5>
                                <span class="text-red-200 cursor-pointer remove-btn">Remove</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
            cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
            cartItems.append(cartRow);
            cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
            cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
        }

        function updateCartTotal() {
            let cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
            let cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row');
            let total = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
                let cartRow = cartRows[i];
                let priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
                let quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0];
                let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''));
                let quantity = quantityElement.value;
                total = total + (price * quantity);
            }
            total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
            document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total;
        }

        ready();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```